# Polymer bind conditional attribute and evaluate attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes, expression, polymer, web-component

I am wondering if it is possible using Polymer expressions to both bind a attribute conditionally to an element while also assigning it a value if the bind is true?

I know how to do both seperately:

```
pattern?="{{someBoolean}}"

pattern="{{someBoolean ? 'value if true' : 'value if false'}}"
```

but have been unsuccessful in accomplishing both without using extra javascript defined in the element's prototype.

Any assistance or advice appreciated!

EDIT:

In above example

```
if (someBoolean)
<input pattern="value if true"/>
else if (!someBoolean)
//pattern attribute is not bound and attribute assignment does not occur
<input/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
<template if="{{ boolean }}">
  {{ patternIfTrue }}
</template>
```

however I think this might be changing in polymer 0.8.

Comment: eh, I hope it does.  It would be nice if they combined the two behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what the point is.
In which case would you need to bind an attribute conditionnaly with another value that true ?
In all HTML attributes, either you need to specify a value, or it is a conditionnaly attribute (ex : hidden="true") that you should remove from the dom, because some browser will not read the value (ex : hidden="false" may be hidden in some browser)

Comment: In my case I am using it on the input tag using the pattern attribute with corresponding regex. Leaving pattern null or blank has lead to inconsistent results with the input element showing an invalid / error state (validity.valid) when it should not.

Comment: And the pattern attribute is still bound to the <input/> element even even when it evaluates to false.

Comment: oh ok. I guess in that case you should just use 2 variables :
 - patternBoolean (true/false)
 - htmlPattern (a computed value from the patternBoolean : see the computed part in the polymer doc : https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#computed-properties), or use a patternBooleanChanged function, to calculate the htmlPattern :
patternBooleanChanged: function() {this.htmlPattern = this.patternBoolean ? 'value if true' : 'value if false';}
And use pattern="{{htmlPattern}}"